# How to parse xml like string getting from webservice

Tags: xml, spring, web-services, spring-mvc

I am consuming a webservice as:

```
public static final String URI2 = "http://www.webservicex.net/length.asmx/ChangeLengthUnit?LengthValue=10.0&fromLengthUnit=Centimeters&toLengthUnit=Inches";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

String  usersMap2 = restTemplate.getForObject(URI2, String.class);
```

and I'm getting response as a string as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<double xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">3.9370078740157477</double>
```

how to parse it to readable and usable format.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML_Processing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could do something like this `DoubleWrapper usersMap2 = restTemplate.getForObject(URI2, DoubleWrapper.class);`

```
@XmlRootElement(name="double", namespace="http://www.webserviceX.NET/")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DoubleWrapper{

    @XmlValue
    private Double value;

    //Getter and setter

}
```

Comment: i was getting response as string. After your process im getting error as:

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not unmarshal to [class com.java.msgconverter.DoubleWrapper]: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.webserviceX.NET/", local:"double"). Expected elements are <{}double>; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.webserviceX.NET/", local:"double"). Expected elements are <{}double>

Comment: Updated with element namespace

Comment: Accepted.  Thanks a lot.